# AnimationDrawable duration attribute

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a problem with android:duration attribute in my xml file. 
That is my code:

```
<animation-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false">
<item
android:drawable="@drawable/eye_1"
android:duration="150" />
<item
.
.
.
</animation-list>
```

There are 8 images.
Here is my Activity code:

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sauron);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();

        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animationImage);
        // imgView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);

        frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imgView
                .getBackground();


     // Get instance of Vibrator from current Context
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        v.vibrate(10000);
    }
    @Override public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) { 
        frameAnimation.start(); 
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus); }

@Override
    protected void onStop()
{
    // Stop play
    super.onStop();
    mp.stop();
}
    }
```

Everything works fine but there is a problem with duration between images. No matter what number i put in android:duration attribute, animation runs very fast. Does anyone know where is a problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the duration is in "milliseconds" meaning 150 is is VERY VERY fast
when 1500 is 1.5 seconds and 150 means 0.15 seconds which is just over 1 tenth of a second

try putting a number in thousands, like 1500 or 3000 and see if that works